# Why doesn't a header respond to code to overwrite styling?

Tags: css

I have a bit of code in this in-development [page](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/). It is the Graphic Design column in the footer. This should display like its neighbors (About Us, Web Design, etc.) but no amount of css, including !important will budge it.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="sub-nav">
     <h5 class="graphic"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></h5>
     <h5 class="graphic"><a href="#">Business Development</a></h5>
     <h5 class="graphic" ><a href="#">Our Blog</a></h5>
     <h5 class="graphic"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h5>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.sub-nav h5.graphic a:link, .sub-nav h5.graphic a:visited    { padding-bottom: 10px !important; color: #22a9e0; border-bottom: none; font-size: 14px : }
.sub-nav h5.graphic a:hover, .sub-nav h5.graphic a:active        { font-size: 14px !important; border-bottom: none; }
```

I want all the h5s in the Graphic design column to look just like the headers next door. I would really appreciate some help getting this wayward section to comply.

Thanks!

Comment: In what way doesn't the "Graphic design column" look like it's cousins? BTW, `h5` isn't really appropriate for navigation links.

Comment: Very obscure question. I can't find anything wrong, and what you are trying to say.

Comment: I looked at that site in chrome, ff 3.6, and ie 8 and don't see a difference in the Graphic Design tab.  I do see differences in how the drop down lists are rendered between them.  However, most of that I suspect has to do with you using an XHTML doctype instead of a HTML STRICT doctype

Comment: Please use question titles that accurately reflect the content of your question.  Imagine someone trying to search for a problem similar to yours months down the line.  That won't happen with a title like "What is this code acting like a teenager?"

Comment: You make a very good point. I apologize for tying to be funny instead of get to the point. It did get attention, but alas, not all the right kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you already have an `h5` style declared in the CSS, this will not be overwritten, no matter what, it seems.

I would just use a `<span>` or an `<li>` like you have "next door", as these aren't headings of any nature :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use FireBug you can see rest all columns are using <ul> to show the selected options. <h5> is used only for main caption. Do that and should fix your problem.